# Proper use of readline in order to display history

Tags: c, history

I'm making a program that shoul act like a real terminal in linux (ubuntu).

What I have is this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   char cmd[500];

   do{
       printf("$ > ");
       fgets(cmd, 499, stdin);
       //executeCommands(cmd);
   }while(strcmp(cmd, "exit\n") != 0);

   return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is: When I press the up key, it should show me what I typed before, and so on... If I press the up key 3 times, it should show me the 3rd latest command used, and so on for the bottom key.

I am not that good with C, but I understood that there is a library readline, and a history one, but I don't know how to use them in order to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want is called command history, and you will have to implement it yourself. Every time the user issues a command append it to a list, then when they hit the up arrow key extract commands from that list.

Comment: List thing you can implement . but to handle arrow key In Linux it will be little bit tricky to implement

Comment: Won't something like this work for getting the key pressed

`if(kbhit()){ c = getch();}`

Comment: You can use `setbuf` to disable the input buffer - enabling you to detect the cursor up/down keys, but you'll have to do all the text input processing yourself, such as backspace, left and right cursor, and so on.

Comment: @OlarAndrei `getch()` is Windows MSVC specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the [GNU readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library (mixing both editable readline feature and history feature). It has documentation for the [Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) itself and for the [history](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html) sub-library.

You'll use `readline` function to read the line, and `add_history` to add some "accepted" line into the history list. You might also want to customize the [completer](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC45).

Spend a couple of hours to read the documentation, it is quite well explained with code samples.

<sup>(the `readline` library is GPL licensed, and is commonly available on Linux. E.g. on Debian install the `libreadline6-dev`  package; I don't know if `readline` works on Windows.)</sup>

You probably should not explicitly use (in your program) [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)-s with `readline`. If you do, dive into the documentation and the source code.

You might want to consider [`ncurses`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html)  library instead. It enables you to code full-screen terminal applications (like `vim` or `emacs` are).

Of course, `readline`  and `ncurses` want the input to be a pseudo-[tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) (so it cannot be a pipe or a file). Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page to understand more the *gory* details, and see [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html)!

<sup>If you want a graphical user interface, dive into [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/). If you want a web interface, you'll need some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) (and a lot of knowledge about web related technologies: HTML5, CSS, Javascript, Jquery, AJAX, ... see [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/) - which is imperfect).</sup>

Comment: Well, I'll start working on it as soon as I'm done reading all the documentaion. Thanks